# swift1.2 -> swift2.0 afnetworking

Tags: swift, afnetworking

```
var parameters = NSDictionary() // or Dictionary<String, AnyObject>()
var error:NSErrorPointer = nil

var request: NSMutableURLRequest = 

AFHTTPRequestSerializer().multipartFormRequestWithMethod(
"POST", 
URLString: "someUrl", 
parameters: parameters, 
constructingBodyWithBlock: { 
    (formData: AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void in  
        formData.appendPartWithFileData(imageData, name: "file", 
           fileName: "fromIos", mimeType: "image/jpeg") 
}, error: error)
```

xcode6 worked fine with this code, xcode7 with swift2 doesn't. 
It says cannot invoke `multipartFormRequestWithMethod` with the given arguments..

> Cannot invoke 'multipartFormRequestWithMethod' with an argument list
>   of type '(String, URLString: String!, parameters: NSDictionary,
>   constructingBodyWithBlock: (AFMultipartFormData!) -> Void, error:
>   NilLiteralConvertible)'

I can't seem to spot the error.

Comment: What does your pod file look like?

Comment: platform :ios, '7.0'  pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.5'

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First off, how does your Podfile look?

Second-
On AFNetworking's GitHub repo, they request Swift developers use [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) instead of AFNetworking:

> Programming in Swift? Try [Alamofire](https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire) for a more conventional set of APIs.

Honestly, though, I would recommend the same- It is built for Swift after all.

Comment: I guess that's why it's so hard to see examples/get feedbacks on AFNetworking + swift. Will try it.

Comment: Btw, my error was due to the fact I had AFNetworking submodule + pod at the same time. Thanks for asking how my pod looks like. I could accept it if you move your previous comment to the answer here.

Comment: Yep. Sorry I couldn't be much help within AFNetworking, but I feel you should switch to Alamofire. They have some great people on StackOverflow, too!